# How to pass element parameter to require.js define call?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a page that is split into "widgets" that are loaded dynamically on the fly - JS with require.js, HTML & CSS with custom JS. This is especially handy because it allows each widget define it's own JS requirements.

For example:

```
define(['jquery', 'mustache'], function($, Mustache) { ...
```

However, in order to target the widget JS functionality into correct element, I need to pass the widgets root element to the javascript, that is loaded with require.js, which is something require.js doesn't support... :/

What I currently have is something like this, where the define call returns an function that does the rendering...

```
// Example.js
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    return function($el) {
        // Render the widget here to "$el"
        $el.html('asdsadads');
    }
});
```

... which is run by the require call...

```
require(['js/example'], function(render) { render($el); });
```

... which works ok with simple structures but with more complex widgets, the init function starts to bloat, which makes it less pretty and harder to read (also, more prone to bugs).

The optimal situation would be something like this...

```
// Example.js 
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    if() { // Check for route and/or other modifiers (is logged in etc)
        $el.html('asdasdasd');
    } else {
        $el.html('qwerty');
    }

});
```

...where the actual functionality is directly inside the define call. Unfortunately, as far as I understand, there is no way to pass the element with the require call, like so...

```
define(['jquery'], function($, $el) {
```

So, what is a man to do? Is there a pattern that I could use to somehow pass the element cleanly to the define call? Or do I have to resort into this ugly callback jungle?

Comment: Personally, I think the pattern you have is better. Modules should be executable, not executed.

Comment: Well, I'm not strictly against said pattern, providing it can be made bit cleaner. However, the problem is that the $el is set only when the callback is ran, so pretty much everything needs to be executed by the callback itself. Which makes it more convoluted and error prone.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a define block is to return a class or function that can be used in another part of your code. This encourages and re-usable, DRY, modular style of coding.

It doesn't make sense for the define module to be aware of $el at the point of creation. What does make sense is that you return a class that gets instantiated with the $el. This way your module is reusable and you return the burden of control to your application, and not the module itself.

Simple example of a module and its use:

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    var MyClass = function(args){
       this.initView(args.$el);
    }
    MyClass.prototype.initView($el){
      //init your view
    }
    return MyClass;
});
```

Then when you can use this module like this:

```
 define(['path/to/myClass'], function(MyClass) {
        var myView = new MyClass({$el: $('.my-selector')}),
           myOtherView = new MyClass({$el: $('.my-other-selector')});
    });
```